# How to display progress on user side in FFMPEG transcoding in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg, progress-bar

I am using Streamio-ffmpeg to process files. The gem shows the progress of the transcoding in the console. I want to display this progress to the user. Is there anyway of doing this?

This is my lib: (Where the transcoding is done)

```
file = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(tmpfile)

encoded_file = File.join(directory, new_name)

file.transcode(encoded_file) { |progress| progressing = (progress * 100).round(2); puts "#{progressing} %"; }
```

The { |progress| progressing = (progress * 100).round(2); puts "#{progressing} %"; } is responsible for printing the progress to the console. Can I display this in my views instead?

Output on console is :-

```
I, [2015-12-21T12:48:55.322814 #19642]  INFO -- : Running transcoding...
ffmpeg -y -i /home/tps/sites/demo_projects/blog/public/uploads/tmp/1450682335-19642-6992/tmpfile  /home/tps/sites/demo_projects/blog/public/uploads/tmp/1450682335-19642-6992/mp4_SampleVideo_1080x720_5mb.mp4

0.0 %

6.63 %

9.57 %

11.4 %

13.46 %

15.86 %

18.3 %

21.64 %

25.03 %

28.61 %

32.09 %

36.62 %

43.29 %

48.6 %

53.23 %

57.69 %

61.68 %

66.49 %

70.1 %

72.91 %

75.75 %

79.07 %

83.73 %

88.81 %

93.07 %

96.72 %

99.05 %

99.97 %

100.0 %

I, [2015-12-21T12:49:10.058592 #19642]  INFO -- : Transcoding of /home/tps/sites/demo_projects/blog/public/uploads/tmp/1450682335-19642-6992/tmpfile to /home/tps/sites/demo_projects/blog/public/uploads/tmp/1450682335-19642-6992/mp4_SampleVideo_1080x720_5mb.mp4 succeeded
```

I tried out "using include ActionController::Live" but i don't get any proper result. I don't know to how to use "include ActionController::Live" in this situation.

Comment: you can show the progress by assign `"#{progressing} %" into an instance variable and then show it on view`

Comment: @RajarshiDas How can i assign it in instance variable ? because this code is in library file so how can i pass lib file variable to my controller as a response and display on view every time when progress is increase ?

Comment: you can use autoload_path to get access the classs of the library and get the array of `"#{progressing} %"` return by the class method and then store it in a instance variable and then show it in a array.each

Comment: also lib has module you can `include` the module in controller and in module add helper_method

Answer (score 1):

in your lib/file_process.rb

```
module FileProcess

  def progress(tmpfile)
   arr = []
   file = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(tmpfile)
   encoded_file = File.join(directory, new_name)
   file.transcode(encoded_file) { |progress| progressing = (progress * 100).round(2); arr << "#{progressing} %"; }
   arr
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.send :helper_method, :progress
  end
end
```

now in controller

```
class FileProcessingsController < ApplicationController
   include 'file_process'
end
```

Now in view you can use `progress` helper method to show the each progress

Comment: How does the controller know which file is being transcoded?

Comment: Yes, but if you upload via Paperclip, how does the file process thing work?

Comment: yes it will then diferent way ....but the user told in lib he mya use a satic file.. but I will post for paper clip